# Custom title bar with list Activity

Tags: java, android, titlebar

I have two activities , One extending the List Activity and other extending the Activty

I want to use custom title bar with both the activties. How is it possible?

If i make a seperate class(extending activity) for custom title bar, then i could only use it for my second activity(that extends activity). How could i use it to extend my first activity(extending list activity)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class named `TitleBarCompat`,and take `Activity` as a parameter in constructor,then  create your custom titlebar in it,and provide a method to use it in Activity,then you can call it in all Activities and its subclasses.

Comment: can you just provide me the abstract example please

Comment: Please show you code for custom titlebar,or i won't know how to achieve your goal concretely.